# Android 2.3 camera autofocus not working

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a problem with the camera of my app:

In android 4+ the autofocus work fine, if there is too much or to few ligth it adjust, but in android 2.3 it does not.

I dont understand well the difference between focus, white balancing or autoexposure so maybe I am not doing what I should do.

This is some of my code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,

  //// more stuff ///

        List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        } else if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);                             
        }

        myCamera.setParameters(p);

        myCamera.startPreview();

        myCamera.autoFocus(null);

   /// more stuff ////
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe

> In android 4+ the <s>autofocus</s> work fine, if there is too much or to few ligth it adjust

is about **autoexposure**. The purpose of autofocus is to keep the picture sharp, not about darkness. You need [setExposureCompensation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29).